# Using a Taylor polynomial to approximate $\cos(\frac14)$ with an error no more than $10^{-12}$

Tags: trigonometry, taylor-expansion, approximation, trigonometric-series

So the Lagrange remainder is given by:

$$R_n(x)=\frac{f^{n+1}(c)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}.$$

We want $\cos(\frac14)$ and we can do it around $a=0$. We know that $f^{n+1}$ is either $\pm\cos x$ or $\pm\sin x$, which are both bounded with an absolute value of $1$:

$$|\cos x|\le1,\qquad |\sin x|\le 1.$$

So we can say the following is true:

$$|R_n(x)|=\frac{f^{n+1}(c)}{(n+1)!}\left(\frac14\right)^{n+1}\le 1\cdot\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\left(\frac14\right)^{n+1} $$

And we get:

$$|R_n(x)|\le \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\left(\frac14\right)^{n+1} $$

Let's try $n=6$:

$$\frac{1}{10^{12}}\le \frac{1}{7!}\left(\frac14\right)^{7} =\frac{1}{5040}\cdot\frac{1}{16384}=\frac{1}{82575360} $$

$$\frac{1}{10^{12}}\le \frac{1}{82575360}  $$

Is $n=6$ enough? Or do I have to continue?

Comment: If $1/82575360$ is the error, that it is larger than $10^{-12}$ and that you want a lower error, what wouldn't you continue?

Comment: @anderstood so are we looking to make the right-side of the inequality  bigger than $\frac{1}{10^{12}}$? and then we'll take n-1?

Comment: The right side is the error. You want to make the error _smaller_ than $10^{-12}$. The higher the order $n$, the lower the error. Try $n=7$.

Comment: for n=7 I get $\frac{1}{9.5*10^{10}} \ge \frac{1}{10^{12}}$, and the inequality is still true, similar to n=6. Maybe I'm getting mixed up as to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You want the error to be less than $10^{-12}$, so you want $|R_n(x)|<\frac{1}{10^{12}}$. You know that
$$|R_n(x)|\leq\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n,$$
so you want to find $n$ such that
$$\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n<\frac{1}{10^{12}},$$
so that you can combine the inequalities to get $|R_n(x)|<\tfrac{1}{10^{12}}$. The bound decreases as $n$ increases, and you have already calculated the bound for $n=7$, which was too big. So try $n=8$, or $n=9$, or...

Comment: So the direction of the inequality I had up earlier was wrong. I pick n=9 and I get:

$\frac{1}{3.8*10^{12}} \le \frac{1}{10^{12}}. which is also true. Do I need to pick n=8 or n=10 now?

Comment: Your calculation shows that $n=9$ is good enough. So certainly $n=10$ is good enough. But is $n=8$ good enough?

Comment: Oh I think I get it now. For n=8 I would get that the inequality is incorrect. Therefore $n\ge9$ is good enough right?

Comment: Exactly. And assuming you don't want to calculate more than necessary, you take $n=9$.